# Lightning Web Component 'lightning-input-rich-text' Change Font Size

Tags: lightning-web-components, richtextarea, lightninginput, formatting

I have a lightning-input-rich-text (LWC) in which I'd like to change the default text size from 12 to 10.  On following the instructions in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation. I can successfully change the fonts in the toolbar of the editor using setFormat however while the toolbar changes the text does not.  I tried to use setRangeText() also and using this I could replace the text in the editor however HTML tags outputted the actual tags instead of keeping the HTML formatting.

Has anyone been able to change the font size of the toolbar in the editor AND the font of the actual text itself contained within the editor? Any help/guidance on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.